fetchCount works but fetch doesn't
I am writing a function in my database object that can read from the database.
I am storing vocab objects
@Model
final class Vocab: Codable{
    var id: Int
    var word: String
    var meaning: String
    var pronunciationUrl: String
    var similar: [[String]]
    var unitNr: Int
    var lessonNr: Int
    var unitLesson: Int
    var practiceData: PracticeData
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.id = id
        self.word = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .word)
        self.meaning = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .meaning)
        self.pronunciationUrl = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .pronunciationUrl)
        self.similar = try container.decode([[String]].self, forKey: .similar)
        self.unitNr = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .unitNr)
        self.lessonNr = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .lessonNr)
        self.unitLesson = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .unitLesson)
        self.practiceData = PracticeData()
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(id.self, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(word.self, forKey: .word)
        try container.encode(meaning.self, forKey: .meaning)
        try container.encode(pronunciationUrl.self, forKey: .pronunciationUrl)
        try container.encode(similar.self, forKey: .similar)
        try container.encode(unitNr.self, forKey: .unitNr)
        try container.encode(lessonNr.self, forKey: .lessonNr)
        try container.encode(unitLesson.self, forKey: .unitLesson)
        try container.encode(practiceData.self, forKey: .practiceData)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case id, word, meaning, pronunciationUrl, practiceData, similar, unitNr, lessonNr, unitLesson
    }
    
    
    
}

func read(predicate: Predicate<Vocab>?,
              sortDescriptors: SortDescriptor<Vocab>...) throws -> [Vocab] {
        let context = ModelContext(self.container)
        let fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Vocab>(
            predicate: predicate,
            sortBy: sortDescriptors
        )
        
        let fetchDescriptor2 = FetchDescriptor<Vocab>()
        let nr = try context.fetchCount(fetchDescriptor)
        
        do {
            return try context.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
        } catch {
            print("Error reading from database")
            return []
        }
    }

Why does context.fetchCount return the correct number of vocab objects, but fetch doesn't return the objects? I get error Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c29454b0) when I run this.

I tried removing the sorting and predicate, but that doesn't change anything.

What is PracticeData? What is self.container, is the read function in a separate type? Please post enough code so we can reproduce the issue.
